# Quay sending html instead of access token for /oauth/authorize request

Tags: oauth-2.0, quay.io

Newbee to Red hat Quay, trying to generate the access token from Postman

I configured the application in the Quay.

[image]

I am trying to generate a token form postman

I am invoking the below URL:

```
http://<ip>/oauth/authorize?client_id=MV69TK1LD94CCT1I6QR5&redirect_uri=http://<ip>/&scope=repo:read
```

Instead of token am getting html for this request.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="quay" class="onprem">

<head>
 <base href="/">


 <title>Authorize Quay-HA-App-Token · Quay</title>






 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/ldn/font-awesome.css-a166e3c966c6.css" type="text/css">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/ldn/bootstrap.min.css-13f668494557.css" type="text/css">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/ldn/cssfamilySourceSansPro300400700-30cd793a4b9b.css" type="text/css">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/ldn/core-icons.css-d500848fee49.css" type="text/css">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/ldn/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css-4b15a4ede750.css" type="text/css">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/ldn/cal-heatmap.css-904c3b9e8a60.css" type="text/css">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/ldn/ng-tags-input.min.css-7782190f81cd.css" type="text/css">


 <!-- Icons -->
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/img/quay_favicon.png" type="image/png" />
 <!-- /Icons -->

</head>

<body ng-class="pageClass + ' ' + (user.anonymous ? 'anon' : 'signedin')" class="co-img-bg-network">
 <div id="co-l-footer-wrapper">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default header-bar co-m-navbar co-fx-box-shadow" role="navigation"></nav>

  <div class="quay-message-bar"></div>
  <div quay-require="['BILLING']">
   <div class="quay-service-status-bar"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="padding-container">
   <div id="co-l-view-container">
    <div ng-class="newLayout ? '' : 'main-panel co-fx-box-shadow-heavy'">

     <div class="container" ng-if="user.anonymous">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
       <div class="user-setup"></div>
      </div>
     </div>

     <div class="container auth-container" ng-if="!user.anonymous">
      <div class="auth-header">
       <span class="avatar" size="48" data="{&#34;color&#34;: &#34;#f7b6d2&#34;, &#34;kind&#34;: &#34;app&#34;, &#34;hash&#34;: &#34;4deba2034a1b248c5a1390bacf85e838&#34;, &#34;name&#34;: &#34;Quay-HA-App-Token&#34;}"></span>
       <h2><a href="http://<ip>/" ng-safenewtab>Quay-HA-App-Token</a></h2>
       <h4>
        <span class="avatar" size="24" data="{&#34;color&#34;: &#34;#f7b6d2&#34;, &#34;kind&#34;: &#34;org&#34;, &#34;hash&#34;: &#34;4deba2034a1b248c5a1390bacf85e838&#34;, &#34;name&#34;: &#34;resiliencyorchestration&#34;}"
              style="vertical-align: middle; margin-right: 4px;"></span>
        <span style="vertical-align: middle">resiliencyorchestration</span>
       </h4>
      </div>

      <div class="auth-scopes">
       <div class="reason">This application would like permission to:</div>
       <div class="panel-group">

        <div class="scope panel panel-default  dangerous ">
         <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
           <div class="title-container">
            <div class="title " data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#scopeGroup"
             data-target="#description-0">
             <i class="fa arrow"></i>
             <i class="fa fa-gear fa-lg"></i>
             <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne">
              Administer Organization
             </a>


             <i class="fa fa-lg fa-exclamation-triangle"
                         data-title="This scope grants permissions which are potentially dangerous. Be careful when authorizing it!"
                         data-container="body" bs-tooltip></i>

            </div>
           </div>
          </h4>
         </div>
         <div id="description-0" class="panel-collapse  in ">
          <div class="panel-body">

           <div class="alert alert-warning">This scope grants permissions which are
            potentially dangerous. Be careful when authorizing it!</div>


           This application will be able to administer your organizations including
           creating robots, creating teams, adjusting team membership, and changing
           billing settings. You should have absolute trust in the requesting
           application before granting this permission.
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>

       </div>
      </div>

      <div class="button-bar">

       <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="$('#confirmAuthorizeModal').modal()">Authorize Application</button>

       <form method="post" action="/oauth/denyapp">
        <input type="hidden" name="client_id" value="MV69TK1LD94CCT1I6QR5">
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect_uri" value="http://<ip>/">
        <input type="hidden" name="scope" value="org:admin">
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="iI1k4xtfDfu5SfnV4q6yjE+msnP6Kqt+/C1fx4q9+9cMgurxcq4nKNBEF6EnpiAK">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
       </form>
      </div>
     </div>


     <!-- Modal message dialog -->
     <div class="modal fade" id="confirmAuthorizeModal">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
       <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
         <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm Authorization</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
         The application <strong>Quay-HA-App-Token</strong> is requesting permission to
         perform actions which are potentially dangerous.
         <br><br>
          Are you sure you want to authorize this application?
        </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
          <form method="post" action="/oauth/authorizeapp" style="display: inline-block">
           <input type="hidden" name="client_id" value="MV69TK1LD94CCT1I6QR5">
           <input type="hidden" name="redirect_uri" value="http://<ip>/">
           <input type="hidden" name="scope" value="org:admin">
           <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="iI1k4xtfDfu5SfnV4q6yjE+msnP6Kqt+/C1fx4q9+9cMgurxcq4nKNBEF6EnpiAK">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Authorize Application</button>
          </form>
          <form method="post" action="/oauth/denyapp" style="display: inline-block">
           <input type="hidden" name="client_id" value="MV69TK1LD94CCT1I6QR5">
           <input type="hidden" name="redirect_uri" value="http://<ip>/">
           <input type="hidden" name="scope" value="org:admin">
           <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="iI1k4xtfDfu5SfnV4q6yjE+msnP6Kqt+/C1fx4q9+9cMgurxcq4nKNBEF6EnpiAK">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Deny</button>
          </form>
         </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
       </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
      </div><!-- /.modal -->



     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div id="co-l-footer-push"></div>
  </div>

  <nav id="co-l-footer" class="page-footer hidden-xs">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <ul>

     <li><a href="https://redhat.com" ng-safenewtab><img src="/static/img/RedHat.svg"></a></li>

     <li quay-require="['BILLING']"><a href="https://docs.quay.io" ng-safenewtab>Documentation</a></li>
     <li quay-require="['BILLING']"><a href="/tos" target="_self">Terms</a></li>
     <li quay-require="['BILLING']"><a href="/privacy" target="_self">Privacy</a></li>
     <li quay-require="['BILLING']"><a href="/security/" target="_self">Security</a></li>
     <li quay-require="['BILLING']"><a href="/about/" target="_self">About</a></li>

     <li quay-require="['BILLING']">
      <span class="quay-service-status"></span>
     </li>
     <li>Quay v3.2.1</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- Modal message dialog -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="couldnotloadModal" data-backdrop="static">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">Uh Oh...</h4>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
      Something went wrong when trying to load Quay! Please report this to <a
       href="mailto:support@quay.io">support@quay.io</a>.
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
     </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
   </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->



  <div class="angular-tour-ui" inline="false" tour="angular_tour_current"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Please help.
Please let me know if any details required.Please let me know if any details required.Please let me know if any details required.Please let me know if any details required.

Answer (score 0):

The below solved my problem.
I am able to see the accesstoken generated for this URL in the browser.

http://quayadmin:Welcome@12345$@/oauth/authorize?client_id=MV69TK1LD94CCT1I6QR5&redirect_uri=http://internal/&scope=repo:read&response_type=token&realm=realm

[image]